# How to convert Python dict to JSON as a list, if possible

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to serialize my Python objects into JSON using `json.dumps`. If you serialize a `dict` using `json.dumps` it will obviously be serialized as a JSON dictionary `{..}`; if you serialize a `list` or a `tuple`, it will be a JSON array.

I want to know if there's any way to easily serialize a Python `dict` as a JSON `list`, if possible. By if possible, I mean if the keys start at 0 and are sequenced, for example:

```
{0:'data',1:'data',2:'data}
```

The above would be serialized into JSON as: `'{"0": "data", "1": "data", "2": "data"}'`, but I would like it to be serialized as `['data','data','data']` since the keys start at 0 and are sequenced.

My reasoning for this is because I have lots of JSON data that is serialized from PHP, where in PHP arrays have keys and if the keys are sequenced as described above, PHP's `json.encode` uses arrays, if they are keyed in any other manner, they are serialized as JSON dictionaries. I want my JSON serializations to match for both my PHP and Python code. Unfortunately, changing the PHP code isn't an option in my case.

Any suggestions? The only solution I have found is to write my own function to go through and verify each python dictionary and see if it can first be converted to a `list` before `json.dumps`.

**EDIT**: This object that I'm serializing could be a `list` or a `dict`, as well, it could have additional dicts inside of it, and lists, and so on (nesting). I'm wondering if there's any 'simple' way to do this, otherwise I believe I can write a recursive solution myself. But it's always better to use existing code to avoid more bugs.

Comment: I'm not sure if `dict.values()` will work in py3k.  Also, FWIW, dicts aren't an ordered data-type, so the order of the serialized list will be well-defined, but "arbitrary" even if you do `json.dumps(list(dict.values()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a solution without recursion... Although you can call your converter from inside the `encode` method of your custom `Encoder`, it would just add unnecessary complexity.

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: d = {"0": "data0", "1": "data1", "2": {"0": "data0", "1": "data1", "2": "data2"}}

In [3]: def convert(obj):
   ...:     if isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
   ...:         return [convert(i) for i in obj]
   ...:     elif isinstance(obj, dict):
   ...:         _, values = zip(*sorted(obj.items()))  
   ...:         return convert(values)
   ...:     return obj

In [4]: json.dumps(convert(d))
Out[4]: '["data0", "data1", ["data0", "data1", "data2"]]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the dictionary into a list of tuples and then sort it, as dictionary items won't necessarily come out in the order than you want them to:

```
items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[0])
values = [item[1] for item in items]
json_dict = json.dumps(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could subclass `json.JSONEncoder` to create your own custom JSON serializer, but that won't allow you to override built-in object types.

If you create your own custom `dictlist` object (or whatever you want to call it) that doesn't extend `dict` or `list` you should be able to override the `JSONEncoder.default` method to create your own custom JSON serializer.

Regardless of whether you create a custom JSON serializer or recursively replace your special `dict` instances with lists you will need a function that accepts a `dict` and returns either a `list` or a `dict` as appropriate.

Here's one implementation:

```
def convert_to_list(obj):
    obj_list = []
    for i in range(len(obj)):
        if i not in obj:
            return obj  # Return original dict if not an ordered list
        obj_list.append(obj[i])
    return obj_list
```